# User python app service does not start on boot

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python3

My user service which is a python script does not run on boot. It runs on raspbian OS as user pi. As most of these questions go I can start the service and it runs fine with `systemctl --user start argus` but it does not start on a reboot.

```
[Unit]
Description=RAL Argus Service

[Service]
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/RAL/Argus/Hextapus_Base.py -bsi=5 -pupd=59 -bm=1
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have run `sudo loginctl --linger $USER` so the service should run even if pi user is not logged in.

The script runs collects data from sensors and shutdowns the device (issues sudo shutdown now) when it is finished collecting data. A RTC wakes up the system again and the scripts runs and repeats the process all over again.

On boot here is the output of `systemctl --user status argus`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl --user status argus
â—� argus.service - RAL Argus Service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/pi/.config/systemd/user/argus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and here is the gist of the script

```
def main():
    args=cli(argv) #parse args

    try:
        
        normal_operation(args)
            
        rtc_time = Hextapus.Get_string_utc_time_pcf(0)
        logger.warning("Issuing Shutdown command at RTC Time: {}".format(rtc_time))    #Indicate os shutdown during hard shutdown and RTC time stamp      
        os.system('sudo shutdown now')    
        return 0
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #This is so when debugging the loops are killed quickly
        logger.warning("Keyboard ESCAPE detected. Shutting Down")
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
       
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Because the service issues a shutdown on the pi when I run systemctl --user start argus I see the following in journalctl

```
Dec 03 20:35:39 raspberrypi python3[27653]: 2020-12-03 20:35:39,502 - WARNING - Issuing Shutdown command at RTC Time: 20201203203543
Dec 03 20:35:43 raspberrypi systemd[385]: Stopping RAL Argus Service...
Dec 03 20:35:43 raspberrypi systemd[385]: argus.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Dec 03 20:35:43 raspberrypi systemd[385]: argus.service: Succeeded.
Dec 03 20:35:43 raspberrypi systemd[385]: Stopped RAL Argus Service.
```

There is no further info in journalctl on the subsequent boot to say the service is running or couldn't start. I'm not sure if the fact that the script issues a shutdown is the cause of my problem.

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is not starting because `pi`'s `--user` bus does not start until `pi` logs in.  While Michal's answer was partially right (you should use `default.target` instead of `multi-user.target` in `--user` mode), the best answer is to put your service on the system bus.

If you want to run this service even without `pi` logging in, then put it on the system bus.  This involves:

- `mv ~/.config/systemd/user/argus.service /etc/systemd/system/`
- Add `User=pi` to the `[Service]` section of `argus.service`.

Now your script has all of the same permissions as if it were run by `pi` on the user bus, except it runs independently of the user-login status.  The only disadvantage is you need to run `sudo` when handling this unit with `systemctl` or `journalctl`.

The main advantage of the `--user` bus is to allow the user to use `systemctl` or `journalctl` without `sudo` to manage specific services.  It also allows starting and stopping of services based on the login or logout of the user. Since your service needs to start without the user input, and without a user login trigger, the system bus is the best place to be.

Comment: "user bus does not start until pi logs in", unless https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6

Comment: True, but then you need to add `loginctl` to a startup script somewhere.  That's really working around the intent of the command.

Comment: Unless `loginctl enable-linger` is persistent. There is no option for `enable-linger` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, and I can't really find anything to suggest it is persistent other than "a user manager is spawned for the user at boot "

Comment: Yes it is, precisely because of what you say. But the documentation could be clearer. It seems to work like this: https://serverfault.com/a/849280

Comment: Thanks.  I learned something today!

Comment: But I agree that for this use case just using a system service is probably more sensible anyway.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I misunderstood the use of user services and I thought loginctl --linger was persistent. I've created another service in the project that runs as a system service so I can use that as a template.

Comment: @MartinJoseph linger **is** persistent (although the command is `loginctl enable-linger`), and if you used `WantedBy=default.target` it should have worked. But it does not mean a system service is not a better solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to run the service under an user instance of systemd you should be using `default.target` not `multi-user.target`. `multi-user.target` is not used by the user instance of systemd.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#default.target1